# Create Batch file for iexpress

Tags: c#, installation, exe, silent, iexpress

I am trying to use `iexpress` to run my batch file which will execute the 2 exe  & 1 msi files for me. when i try to do it manually, it works.

following is the code in my batch file.

```
Start /wait %CD%\1.exe /q
Start /wait %CD%\2.exe /q
msiexec.exe /i "%CD%\3.msi"
```

but this doesn't seem to be working when i create an exe file from iexpress.
[image]

[Reference](http://www.itscodingtime.com/post/Combine-Setup-MSI-and-EXE-into-a-single-package-with-IExpress.aspx)

Above mentioned article has some code(to copy files to temp folder) & but i am not able to understand the syntax.

```
MKDIR %Tmp%\<UNIQUE PRODUCT NAME>
XCOPY . %Tmp%\<UNIQUE PRODUCT NAME> /S /E /Y
%Tmp%\<UNIQUE PRODUCT NAME>\setup.exe
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that, as you can see from your screenshot, the batch file is being executed by `command.com`, not `cmd.exe`. (If you don't specify an interpreter, IExpress uses `command.com`. Ouch.) So there are no variables like `%cd%` or `%~dp0`.

You likely don't need them anyhow. But you do need to execute your batch file explicitly in IExpress like:

```
cmd.exe /c file.bat
```

so that it uses a modern command interpreter.

The second bit of code in your question makes the files persistent (ie they won't be deleted after the IExpress archive terminates) by `xcopy`ing them to a different directory.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what it means:

**1)** Creates a directory(`MKDIR`) with name of "UNIQUE PRODUCT NAME" in the path stored in `%TMP%` Environment Variable, which normally points to: C:\DOCUME~1\yourusername\LOCALS~1\Temp

```
MKDIR %Tmp%\<UNIQUE PRODUCT NAME>
```

**2)** Then copy recursively all installation files from current folder into the new folder created before.
XCOPY arguments:

`/S`          Copies directories and subdirectories except empty ones.

`/E`           Copies directories and subdirectories, including empty ones.
             Same as `/S /E`. May be used to modify `/T`.

`/Y`           Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an
             existing destination file.

```
XCOPY . %Tmp%\<UNIQUE PRODUCT NAME> /S /E /Y
```

**3)** Finally execute the application from the new location
%Tmp%\\setup.exe

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the explanation..but i didn't help me in solving d issue

Comment: How does your latest script looks like? Do you still get the same error message shown in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `%CD%` with `%~dp0`

Assuming that 1.exe is in the same folder as your batch script.

Comment: I think it's because you're running it from the APPDATA temp directory. Can you move the batch script and the exe somewhere else and try?

Comment: I can't control it. The temp directory is chosen by the iexpress tool itself.

Comment: Neither will work, because this is all running from `command.com`. The batch file must be started via `cmd /c` for those to function.

Answer (score 0):

Your %CD% is not working. Please be sure that CMD extensions are enabled (type CMD /x to enable and CMD /y to disable) then expand the %CD% with this code

```
SET CURDIR=%CD%
Start /wait "%CURDIR%\1.exe" /q 
Start /wait "%CURDIR%\2.exe" /q 
msiexec.exe /i "%CURDIR%\3.msi"
```

And I'm not sure that you can start an exe from that location (APPDATA) for security reasons.

Comment: `%cd%` is not working because the script is executing via `command.com`, as shown in the screenshot above. If the script is executed via `cmd /c`, then `%cd%` will work.

Comment: Well, this is rather old,but probably you are right. +1 to your answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for this forum discussion.Finally i could able to compile all msi files and executables in an one .exe file.

Complete procedure as follows create a batch file

> `echo on`
>
> `SET CURDIR=%CD%`
>
> `msiexec.exe /i "%CURDIR%\1.msi"`
>
> `"%CURDIR%\3.EXE"`
>
> `"%CURDIR%\setup.exe"`
>
> `echo off`

You can arrange any number of exe files or msi files as you wish and save the batch file as yourfile.bat.
Now the tricky part is before you proceed to Iexpress, convert the batch file to exe with the software provided by  http://www.f2ko.de/programs.php?pid=b2e

Now when you run the program keep the 'Invisible Application' checked to hide the command prompt.You can also encrypt your exe with the password.*'Delete at Exit'* is optional as the temporary folder will be automatically deleted when the execution of files completed.
Once you successfully compile the batch file,execute the .exe file created.
Bingo!! you'll not see the command prompt window and your applications start executing sequentially.

Begin your Iexpress tool and Add all your files present in the batch file(except batch file).On the ‘Install Program to Launch’ screen, leave the Post Install Command **blank** and find the following in the Install Program dropdown:'**demo.exe**'and proceed further to create your complete bunch of single package. Cheers!!