# iexpress not executing installer

Tags: iexpress

I have an install.bat file and a resource folder. so long as these two files are in the same directory, if you run install.bat, it will install a my lwjgl game. so what im trying to do is make a self extracting file that when completed runs the launch.bat file. I have tried using iexpress, and got it working for the most part. i have added in all my files and such so it will extract to some directory and then i can run the install.bat file to get my program to work. thing is though, i want the exe i created with iexpress to launch install.bat when its finished. so, i tried using the option in iexpress that says it will execute a command when finished the "installation" (using quotes because its not the actual installation, just extracting the files to some directory specified by the user). when i get to the step where it says what i would like to execute during and after the "installation". during the installation i left blank. after the installation i chose the install.bat file. when i try to click next though, it tells me i must choose something for the command during the extraction. I don't have anything specific to do during the installation so i just said "echo." (without quotes). after i was done i tried running the installer. before it even prompted me for a folder to extract to, it told me that echo. could not be executed. so i went back into my installation (via a .sed file) and changed the "echo." to "pause". that didn't work either. i then read on another website that in order to run a file the way i would like to, i put the file name in both the during and after installation boxes. i tried doing that and it didn't work either. can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly you will need to specify what the iexpress must do at the post install command option provided so that `cmd.exe` is used instead of `command.com`, eg:

```
cmd.exe /c filethatyouwanttorun.bat
```

Refer to the question: [Create Batch file for iexpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448897/create-batch-file-for-iexpress).

You can use the SED file and then modify the self extraction directive. This will run the batch file that you wanted to run and then install the application. (If you have chosen the option to extract and run an installation in iexpress, a temp folder will be used for the extraction I suppose.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question exactly but perhaps a few points would help:

1. If you want a "do nothing" command, you can use something like:

   ```
   cmd /c echo.
   ```
2. There is no "command during the extraction". There's only an *install program* and a *post install command*. Both of these execute after extraction. If you only need to execute one batch file, put it in the *install program* line and leave the *post install command* blank.
3. You can't ask the user for an extraction path and execute a file. You can only do one or the other. (The install program could prompt the user and copy the files there, though.)